# Why can't I access a particular url from a remote server?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a website for a church using Angular and I'm unable to access a particular webpage of the site from apppsot.com where it's currently being hosted. Meanwhile that particular webpage is accessible from my localhost server.

Here's the path to the webpage in the angular routing module

```
{ path: 'membership/enroll',       component: MembershipEnrollmentComponent}
```

and here's the error I get when trying to access it through appspot

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /membership/enroll was not found on this server.
```

Comment: The server responses with 404 not found?

Comment: Is your application hosted in a subfolder perhaps? If so, you probably want to take a look at the [base href](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag). When buildling for deployment, you can specify it as `ng build` (param)[https://angular.io/cli/build#options]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Path Location Strategy and use base tag in your index.html file like this

```
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
```

Check https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy for more information